# Try to show values through vue js with laravel in drop down

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-7

Try to show countries in dropdown get from database through vue.js in laravel 7. countries didn't show in dropdown.

**Template code**:

```
<template>
<div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
        <label>Country of Birth </label>
        <select name="birth_county" v-model='country' @change='getCities()'>
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select country</option>
            <option v-for='data in countries' :value='data.id'>{{ data.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Script Code**:

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            country:0,
            countries:[],
            city:0,
            cities:[]
        }
    },
    methods:{
        getCountries: function (){
            axios.get('/get-countries')
                .then(function (response){
                    this.countries = response.data;
                }.bind(this));
        },
        getCities: function (){
            axios.get('/get-cities', {
                params: {
                    id: this.country
                }
            })
                .then(function (response){
                    this.cities = response.data;
                }.bind(this))
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.getCountries()
    }
}
</script>
```

I am trying to show countries in dropdown.

Comment: it seems like there's a problem with your response. can you post the response which you get from ```/get-countries``` ?

Comment: I successfully show countries but now I didn't show cities. There is a problem. I don't know what is..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a syntax error with  `@change='getCities()'` this will call getCities immediately, you'd want `@change='getCities'` instead